# Кнопка с методом созданная в другом методе с помощью connect

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton

При попытке создать кнопку из метода `openfile()`, кнопка создается, но при нажатии на неё выдает ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'anotherone'

ругается на команду

```
but1.clicked.connect(self.anotherone)
```

Почему `self` это `bool` и как сделать кнопку с обращением к другому методу?

---

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

mywindow = QWidget()
mywindow.resize(250, 150)

mywindow.setWindowTitle('My Window')
mywindow.show()



class Main(mywindow):
    but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(mywindow)
    but.show()
    but.move(1, 1)
    but.setText("Создать кнопку")
    but.setFixedWidth(200)


    def create(self):
        but1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(mywindow)
        but1.show()
        but1.move(1, 25)
        but1.setText("Создать ещё")
        but1.setFixedWidth(200)
        but1.clicked.connect(self.anotherone)

    def anotherone(self):
        but2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(mywindow)
        but2.show()
        but2.move(1, 50)
        but2.setText("Больше нет")
        but2.setFixedWidth(200)

    but.clicked.connect(create)
    app.exec()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Изменил код в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаю что будет делать ваше приложение, но чтобы оно работало без ошибок, надо сделать примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.but.move(1, 1)
        self.but.setText("Создать кнопку")
        self.but.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.but.clicked.connect(self.create)

    def create(self):
        but1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        but1.show()
        but1.move(1, 25)
        but1.setText("Создать ещё")
        but1.setFixedWidth(200)
        but1.clicked.connect(self.anotherone)

    def anotherone(self):
        but2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        but2.show()
        but2.move(1, 50)
        but2.setText("Больше нет")
        but2.setFixedWidth(200)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle('My Window')
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]